# Vue Class Based Component Warning: Property is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-class-components

I am trying to create a vue component with vue-class-component and typescript (found here https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component). From what I understand, data is defined in the class, as I have done below - yet I receive the error:

```
"[Vue warn]: Property or method "test" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property."
```

Here is a stripped down version of my actual code, but it still doesn't work:

```
<template>

  <div id="vue-test">
    <input v-model="test"/>
    {{test}}
  </div>

</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import Component from 'vue-class-component';

@Component({
})
export default class AppearanceDialogVue extends Vue {
  public test: string = '100';
}

</script>
```

EDIT: It appears that changing 'test's declaration to

```
public test: string;
```

worked

Comment: Did you try `test = '100';` without `public` and `string`?

Comment: Your code runs for me without error/warning.

Comment: I have the same issue, I tried every combination for the test declaration, but I get the error no matter what I do.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution to this issue, need to add a constructor and initialize the property in the constructor

```
<template>
<section class="dropdown" style="background-color: #dde0e3">
  <select class="btnList" v-model="foo">
    <option v-for="item in selectedfooData" :value="item" :key="item.id">{{item}}</option>
    </select>
    {{foo}}
  </section>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
  @Component
  export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {  
  private foo: string;
  private selectedfooData : string[] = [
   'one',
   'two'
  ]
  construtor() { 
    super();
    this.foo = '';
  }

 }
</script>
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21241138)

Comment: Sorry, have found the solution to this issue, edited the answer @JobinJoseph