# "Property or method "foo" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render" Vuejs Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, v-model

> Property or method "foo" is not defined on the instance
>   but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is
>   reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by
>   initializing the property.

I have worked with vuejs, now I'm shifting to typescript facing this issue for trying to access a simple property and making it reactive.

Similar question has been asked but no solution yet :
[Vue Class Based Component Warning: Property is not defined on the instance but referenced during render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51140028/vue-class-based-component-warning-property-is-not-defined-on-the-instance-but-r/53002608#53002608)

```
<template>
    <section class="dropdown" style="background-color: #dde0e3">
      <select class="btnList" v-model="foo">
        <option v-for="item in selectedfooData" :value="item" :key="item.id">{{item}}</option>
      </select>
      {{foo}}
    </section>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
 import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
 @Component
 export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {  
   private foo: string;
     private selectedfooData : string[] = [
     'one',
     'two'
     ]
 }
</script>
```

I have tried a workaround for this by adding the property as a prop but this gives me error saying, So what is the right way to try this out ?

> Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten
>   whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or
>   computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated:
>   "foo"

```
 @prop()
 private foo: string;
```

Comment: did you try adding `foo` inside vue's `data` object?

Comment: This is `class based` approach so there is `no data object` present, we need to define a constructor. @Capt.Teemo

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution to this issue, need to add a constructor and initialize the property in the constructor

```
<template>
<section class="dropdown" style="background-color: #dde0e3">
  <select class="btnList" v-model="foo">
    <option v-for="item in selectedfooData" :value="item" :key="item.id">{{item}}</option>
    </select>
    {{foo}}
  </section>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
  @Component
  export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {  
  private foo: string;
  private selectedfooData : string[] = [
   'one',
   'two'
  ]
  construtor() { 
    super();
    this.foo = '';
  }

 }
</script>
```

Comment: initializing the property directly, as you do in selectedfooData, should have the same effect as in the constructor